# How to disable indexing/search on certain file types in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

For one reason or another, I have a few nasty JSON files in my XCode project. When I do searches, they will sometimes get hung up on these files.

Is there a way to prevent XCode4 from indexing certain file types, or files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to the search navigator (⌘+3)
2. click on the magnifier within the search field
3. choose "Show Find Options"
4. click on "Find in", there should be "Workspace"
5. use "Custom…" and select "Path Extension" "is not equal to" "json"
6. give it a name e.g. `SearchWithoutJson`
7. next time you can enter something in the search field and select your search setting

//EDIT: actually the next search with selecting `SearchWithoutJson` doesn't work. You still need to display the search options and make sure the right one is selected in "Find in"

Comment: +1!!! My "Find Options" were hidden and this indirect answer led me to the option "Show Find Options". It was driving me nuts

Comment: What is interesting here is that it's called Path Extension instead of the well know File Extension. Also there is an option `Type` referring to different file types (C, C++ source, Ruby, Java, Javascript, etc.), which is still lacking swift file type in the latest Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

Don't include the JSON files in your project at all.

Instead insert a custom build phase that copies these files into the application bundle.

Or maybe you can put all JSON files into one big file, so indexing will be faster.